# How can I access session attribute in Facelets page

Tags: java, jsf, session, authentication, facelets

I have implemented a login form using JSF and PrimeFaces.
I used [this example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialogLogin.jsf) in the PrimeFaces showcase website.

I have a Facelets page to show a dataTable. Now I need to integrate the above login form with this table page. So I added few lines in to LoginBean.java to handle session attribute.

```
     if (username.equals(getUsername_db()) && password.equals(getPassword_db())) {//valid user and paward
        loggedIn = true;
        msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Welcome", getUsername_db());
        //new lines
        FacesContext context2 = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) context2.getExternalContext().getSession(true);
        session.setAttribute("user", username);
        //end of new lines
        ...
```

I need to hide a column from the dataTable, if the user is not logged in.
Now my problem is, how can I access session attribute inside my Facelets page?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You've stored the logged-in user as a session attribute with the name "user".

So it's in EL available as follows:

```
#{user}
```

You can just use the `empty` keyword in EL to check if it's present or not (i.e. if it's logged-in or not) and you can use JSF component's `rendered` attribute to instruct whether to generate HTML output or not.

```html
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{not empty user}">
    <p>Welcome #{user}, you have been logged in!</p>
</h:panelGroup>
```

In your specific case of hiding a table column, just use it as follows:

```html
<p:column rendered="#{not empty user}">
    ...
</p:column>
```

A nicer way to store a session attribute is using `ExternalContext#getSessionMap()`. This way your code is free of smelly `javax.servlet.*` imports.

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("user", username);
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, why the following check?

```
if (username.equals(getUsername_db()) && password.equals(getPassword_db())) {
```

Why don't you just do a `SELECT ... FROM user WHERE username=? AND password=?` in SQL? Or don't you trust the DB that it returns the right row?

Comment: Thanks BalusC. But I got the user as an object in the view. something like this showed "User@1a8b71e". Anyway I got <h:panelGroup rendered="#{not empty user}"> part from your answer to solve my problem. I removed the session setting part and set LoginBean class as SessionScoped. And I was able to get values directly inside my panelGroup tag.Thanks again for the SQL advice. I changed it using prepared statements.

Comment: Apparently `username` as shown in your code is not a `String` at all. Perhaps you oversimplified the code in the question? By the way the SQL comment wasn't meant to hint about prepared statements. You're comparing the username and password **twice** (once in DB and another afterwards in Java). This makes no sense. Just check if DB returned one record or not, that's all. You don't need to compare the username/password once again which you already asked the DB to check and return.

Comment: Got it! but in my last sql query I just used only username with the Where clause. like : String query = "SELECT username,password FROM user WHERE username = '" + uname + "'; "; So I could just remove username.equals(getUsername_db() part. I need only to check password in this case... thanks for you suggestion.

Comment: This makes also no sense. Just add password to the WHERE. SQL queries should *always* be written that way that it returns **exactly** the data you want, without any necessary additional checks afterwards. By the way, with string-concatenating user-controlled input in SQL string like that you're opening a huge SQL injection attack hole. Use prepared statements.