# Can we access session scope variables directly in JSF xhtml files

Tags: jsf, xhtml, session-variables

Hi I am working on a JSF project, I will like to access some session level variables onto my xhtml UI pages directly without using any managed bean.

Just wanted to know if this is possible and if yes than how?

Thanks

Comment: The way to go is using a `@SessionScoped` bean to store them. Then, you can access it from the view.

Comment: Do you know how to get [HTTP session](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html)? Do you know how to [set its attributes](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setAttribute(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object))? Have you checked [`ExternalContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html) documentatuion?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I access session attribute in Facelets page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13047446/how-can-i-access-session-attribute-in-facelets-page)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes its possible

If the bean doesnot exits then put it in session first

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put(key,object);
```

And to use the bean on xhtml page use

```
<h:outputText value="#{sessionScope.key}" />
```

Comment: Session attributes are also directly available in EL. Have a [look](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13047815/1199132)

Comment: If the key is a session variable, it can use used in an XHTML page without any Managed Bean.

    <h:outputText value="#{key}" />