# JSF expression language facecontext session

Tags: jsf, primefaces, el

I want to know, if it is possible to access the session as

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false);
```

from EL, the thing is I want to know if the user has login or not and make possible if?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19445455/can-we-access-session-scope-variables-directly-in-jsf-xhtml-files

Answer (score 2):

There is an implicit session object available in EL as `#{session}` 
But it looks like returned session will under the hood be retrieved as follows:

```
return extCtx.getSession(true);
```

So, if you really need to get it from EL with `false` flag, you can put your code to method of some managed bean and call it.

Or you can call getSession from implicit request object:

`#{request.getSession(false)}`