# Passing values from jsp to xhtml

Tags: java, jsf, variables, xhtml

I am totally new to this. I am developing a simple web application where I have a login page to enter username, password, usertype. Depending on the usertype it should open different xhtml pages.

I want to know how can I pass the value of the userID to the pages for further reuse?

```
session.setAttribute("name", userName);
```

how can I call this variable from the xhtml page?

Thanks.

Comment: I would start by first going through this short [JSP Tutorial](http://www.jsptut.com/), then coming back here if you are still having issues. Embedding the values of server-side variables into the output HTML is a fundamental and basic task.

Comment: Thanks.. I am still learning. Highly appreciated.

Comment: I read the tutorial, what I cant get to is how to call the "name" from an xhtml page that is redirected by the login.jsp page.

Comment: If you're not generating the target page with a servlet, then you either have to generate the XHTML page with a JSP, or pass it as a GET parameter on redirect, or pass it in a cookie, or any other way you'd pass information around when using non-generated pages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I access session attribute in Facelets page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13047446/how-can-i-access-session-attribute-in-facelets-page)