# Language internationalization in @ViewScoped

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I found this tutorial how to use different languages in JSF page.

http://memorynotfound.com/jsf-internationalisation-i18n/

Bug in my application all managed beans are in @ViewScoped. How I can set just with one `h:selectOneMenu` in all pages default language?

Comment: For all pages to have same stored locale you could use `@SessionScoped` and store there locale, then `@Inject` it to your beans or save it in [session attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13047815/3803447).

Comment: Can be a small session bean to keep language... you can use more that one bean per page... (just in case you didn't know)